# how can i add print css or !important for ng-style?

Tags: html, angularjs, printing, ng-style

```
<div class="secondary-value" 
  ng-style="{ background: totalColour || '#0000ff' }"></div>
```

How can i add print css to ng-style? or how can i use !important in ng-style attribute. i'm trying to print the page but the ng-style attribute css doesn't print.

Comment: Please add more information (code, ...) that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: <div class="secondary-value" ng-style="{ background: totalColour || '#0000ff' }"></div>  im trying to print the page but the ng-style background color is not printing. i do not know how to add !important to this attribute.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is hard to read and easy to overlook. I can't help you because this is about AngularJS, I only know Angular.

Comment: im adding the code in the question but its ripping out the code when i post the question.

Comment: There are buttons in the toolbar to format code, then it won't be ripped.

Comment: updated the question. Thank you gunter.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ng-style you need to use quotes aswell

```
<div class="secondary-value" 
 ng-style="{ 'background-color': totalColour || '#0000ff !important' }"></div>
```

Comment: Updated the ng-style with quotes but it doesn't make much difference. when im adding !important to the ng-style css i get error saying token '!' is unexpected.

Comment: updated my answer, this should be working without error.